# gem bundle install from local resource

Tags: rubygems, bundle

can I redirect gem source to my web server path, where I'll download all necessary gem bundles and put there? I want to use those by "`bundle install`"

GemFile will fetch those from http://rubygems.org as it is defined on there. 
I usually got an error like "too many requests" (seems internet congestion issues).

is it possible to redirect gem source path to my local server?

Answer (score 20):

TL;DR: Use the [`:path` option](http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html#PATH-path-).

---

Assuming you want to install a gem from a not reachable resource, such as:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

and you can't install the gem using `bundle install` because of a firewall or something.

Following these steps:

1. Download the file (using any approach you can, e.g. using http_proxy, from https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/zipball/master)
2. Put the downloaded file into a folder, such as `vendor/gems/rails_admin`, and the file in it should look like:

   ```
   $ ls vendor/gems/rails_admin
   app  config  Gemfile  Gemfile31  lib  LICENSE.md  rails_admin.gemspec  Rakefile  README.md  screenshots  spec
   ```
3. Now let's modify your Gemfile:

   ```
   gem 'rails_admin', :path => "vendor/gems/rails_admin"
   ```
4. Run `bundle`, works!

Comment: This worked well for me for using a patched gem in my bundle: clone the gem's repo somewhere and patch it, then set its absolute path in the `Gemfile`. The main problem is that now you have a locally modified `Gemfile` that you mustn't commit.

Answer (score 6):

you can do `bundle install --local`

from [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_update.html) more detail

Comment: This worked well for me, for using a patched gem in my bundle: clone the gem's repo somewhere, patch it and build the gem package, then create a `vendor/cache` directory in your app's directory, copy the gem file there and run `bundle install --local`. It took me a while to figure out that the correct directory is `./vendor/bundle` and there is no way to configure it to something more reasonable (I have a portable bundler config file in the my git repo that sets `BUNDLE_PATH` to something reasonable, but it is ignored) and now I have this (mostly useless) dir stuck in the middle of my project.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to declare additional Rubygems source in your Gemfile, like this?

```
source "http://youserver.com"
```