# making a new rails project without downloading gems / locking all gem versions in the Gemfile in a new rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to start a new rails project, but I am working offline, so rails won't be able to download all the gems it wants if I do rails new foo. I already have everything i need for a new project (thor, arel,etc,,,I've been using this computer for rails development). How can I get rails to bypass the downloads it normally tries to do and use what I already have? Also, does anybody know how to start off with all of the gems in the Gemfile explicitly versioned so that bundle doesn't try and download updates unless you take the versions off (default version lock)?

Comment: it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088408/gem-bundle-install-from-local-resource

Comment: thanks, baldrick. Not sure about the full answer yet, but that was part of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can create a new rails project without triggering bundler:

```
rails new foo --skip-bundle
```

Next, you'll have to edit the `Gemfile` and manually set the gem versions to those that you have installed on your machine. Using pessimistic operator `~>` is fine. Example:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'
```

Then install the gems on your local machine with bundler:

```
bundle install --local
```

Comment: is there any way to make these two steps in to configuration permanently?